# Have trouble with JS/JQ on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

```
   $(document).mouseup(function (e){
      var container = $(".box");

      if (!container.is(e.target) )
      {
          container.css('visibility','hidden');
      }
   });
```

It works on Chrome, Opera, Mozilla, Edge and even IE9. But not on Safari
https://jsfiddle.net/kt2wf5g3/

Comment: Please provide fiddle link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kt2wf5g3/

Comment: fiddle is blocked